# How to send a resource collection using Restangular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, restangular

Let's say I want to send a `DELETE` request to a resource like `/products` and I want to delete multiple products.

The whole request would be to the following URI: `/products/ids=1&ids=2&ids=3`

How can I issue a request like the above one using Restangular?

For now, the issue is that `customDELETE` receives query string params using an object. Hence, it can't define the same parameter more than once...

Comment: `/products/ids=1,2,3` - You can then split the ids by comma *OR* loop your ids before calling `/products/1` then `/products/2`, ...

Comment: @Weedoze I believe I've already got the solution. I'll post it as soon as I could verify that it really works. About your proposal, I could do so, BTW my server tech can automatically handle resource collections using the other approach...

Comment: @Weedoze Check my own answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was an easy one:

```
products.one().customDELETE(null, { ids: [1,2,3,5] } });
```